# UITableView Custom Cell is showing only one line of text initially for all the cells

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, ios6

I am using a custom cell to show the post of Facebook pages using Facebook Graph API. I am getting the JSON data, and i am converting all the post into the msgArray, then passing this msgArray to my view Controller in which i have my table view and then using this msgArray to populate the data in the custom cell. But when i am showing the data in the custom  cell it is loading only one line of text in the label(postText: labelName)  for all the cells of the table view and when i am scrolling it up and down then few of the cell are showing complete text and few are only showing one line of text which depends how much i am waiting for the text to get loaded.

Below is my code for the table view:

```
(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{

    return [msgArray count];
}

(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSString *cellIdentifier=@"Cell";


    CustomCell *cell= [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];



    //UITableViewCell *tablecell=[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];

    if(cell==nil)
    {


      NSArray *nib=[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"CustomCell" owner:self options:nil];


        cell=[nib objectAtIndex:0];


    }

//if(cell==nil)
  //  {
    //    cell=[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
    //}




        cell.postText.lineBreakMode=NSLineBreakByWordWrapping;
    cell.postText.numberOfLines=0;
        [cell.postText sizeToFit];

     cell.postText.text=[msgArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];



    return cell;

}



(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
   //This function is calculating my height for each row depending upon text length which is correct.

    NSString *text=[msgArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    CGSize constraint=CGSizeMake(300,20000.0f);

    CGSize size=[text sizeWithFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:17.0] constrainedToSize:constraint lineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByWordWrapping];

    CGFloat height=MAX(size.height,44.0f);

    return height+(100*2);


}
```

One more thing, If i am using Default UITableViewCell, and set the text as `cell.textLabel.text=[msgArray objectatIndex:indexPath.row];`, it is showing data properly.

Please help me in getting out of this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: you have to adjust postText height as well... set the anchor for postText relative to parent, as height resize textView should also resize... also use CGSize constraint=CGSizeMake(300,MAXFLOAT);

Comment: Faiziii, I am not able to get. Can you please write a line of code here it will help a lot.

Comment: Faiziii, I am not able to get. Can you please write a line of code here it will help a lot.

But it you are talking about resizing Label's Size, i have also done that. It was not working.
 CGSize maximumLabelSize=CGSizeMake(296, 9999);
        
        CGSize expectedLabelSize=[[msgArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]
          sizeWithFont:lblPost.font constrainedToSize:maximumLabelSize
        lineBreakMode:lblPost.lineBreakMode];
        
        CGRect newFrame=lblPost.frame;
      newFrame.size.height=expectedLabelSize.height;
      
      lblPost.frame=newFrame;

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to change its numberOfLines property to 0? By default it's 1.

`cell.textLabel.numberOfLines = 0;`

Comment: Yes Please check my code, I have written cell.postText.numberOfLines=0;

Comment: One More Thing I removed this custom cell code and added a UILabel at runtime and added my text on that label, and added it on the cell using [cell.contentMode addSubview:lbl]; 
It is showing up my cell blank, I dont know why my Label is not visible on the UITableViewCell. I must be doing something very silly which i am not able to get.

Comment: Did you try to adjust label height and font size? Try with a smaller font size and fit label height to the cell height

Comment: yep i tried, I decrease the font label to 14.0 earlier it was 17.0, still it is showing only two lines of text. Again, when i am scrolling it up and down sometimes my whole cell's text becomes visible sometimes it is showing only two lines. Also, my upper concern is resolved, i.e. i removed the customCell class and created a label dynamically, loaded text in that and added to my UITableViewCell and it is working fine. But still i dont know why my custom cell is not working for me. :-(